# Overwrite sub-object in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a nested hash, say:

```
data = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: :f
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

another hash:

```
update = {g: :h}
```

and a path:

```
path = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

I want to replace the sub-hash of `data` specified by `path` with `update`, so that I end up with:

```
data == {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          g: :h
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's easy to navigate to the sub-hash:

```
_data = data
path.each{|p| _data = data[p]}
```

but that doesn't work, as `_data = update` changes what `_data` refers to, and does not actually change the value of `data[:a][:b][:b][:d]`.

And while I can write an expression that results in the sub-hash, attempting to assign it results in a syntax error:

```
> (path.inject(data){|_data, s| _data[s]}) = update
SyntaxError: unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Hash#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-replace)

```
> path.inject(data){|_data, s| _data[s]}.replace({g: :h})
> data
# => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>{:g=>:h}}}}}
```

Comment: Ah, no, I need the `:e` key/value pair removed. Sorry! (Otherwise, deep_merge does the trick)

Comment: @Narfanator probably wants `Hash#replace`.

Comment: You could also write `path[0...-1].inject(data){|_data, s| _data[s]}[path[-1]] = {g: :h}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def substitute(data, path, update)
  (data[path.first] = update; return) if path.size == 1
  substitute(data[path.first], path.drop(1), update)
end

substitute(data, path, update)
  #=> nil
data
  #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>{:g=>:h}}}}}
```

To return `data` (as well as modify it), add `data` as the last line.

Comment: Nice recursive version. You could use `first`/`drop(1)` instead of `shift` to avoid `dup`/modifications on `path`.

Comment: @sschmeck, thanks. I edited. I originally had `path.first` and `path[1..-1]`, but couldn't bring myself to using something that ugly. `path.drop(1)` is less ugly.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution building an updated copy of the nested hash (Ruby 1.8.7).

```
def substitute(data, path, update)
  if path.empty? 
    update
  else
    first, *rest = path
    Hash[*data.map { |k, v| first == k ? [k, substitute(v, rest, update)] : [k ,v] }.flatten]
  end
end

result = substitute(data, path, update)
puts "In  #{data.inspect}"   # => In  {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>{:e=>:f}}}}}
puts "Out #{result.inspect}" # => Out {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>{:g=>:h}}}}}
```

Comment: Reads well. I think `first, *rest = path` is worth the extra line of code and the creation of two variables.